# MenuItem in blackberry application

Tags: java, blackberry, user-interface, thread-safety

I use some menuitems in my application and I have a question about the run method which I override.

```
private MenuItem menuItemUpdate = new MenuItem("Update", 0, 0) {
    public void run() {
        // Can I write GUI code here?

    }
};
```

As the comment states, can I write GUI code here? I can`t right? Since I am not on the GUI thread? Should I use the invokeLater-method when I have code that changes the GUI? And what about Dialogs, should they be invoked in invokeLater-methods as well?

And is it necassary to override the run-method of MenuItem if I have made another thread which will be invoked when the user selects the menu item? Could I start that thread in the constructor instead? And leave the run method un-overridden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write UI code there, because the UI thread handles the user's actions, and calls the menu item code.   All user interaction is handled by the UI thread.

Comment: you can also use the run method to `pushScreen()` there, where you have designed your `Ui or Gui` ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - because it's on the UI thread, for example:

```
private MenuItem menuItemUpdate = new MenuItem("Update", 0, 0) {
    public void run() {
        Show.status("Huzzah!");
    }
};
```

And it seems to be general rule that you don't add any locking around - until you get an IllegalStateException ;-)